# Merge statement in SSIS

Tags: sql, merge, ssis

I am using MERGE statement in SSIS to populate a fact table. This table has close to 2.5 million records and my source table is from PeopleSoft. My problem is that sometimes records get deleted in the source table when a student drops the class and I am trying to retain this record in the datawarehouse. I am using when matched and when not matched statement in my merge statement.
Question - If the record is deleted in the source and I execute my merge statement, since the record no longer matches any join, will it still stay the same or it gets wiped out?

Comment: If you're only doing `UPDATE`/`INSERT` on your fact table, and no actual `DELETE`, then you won't have any issues.

Comment: @Chris Mack thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The record will stay the same.  Unmatched records are not automatically deleted.